# Using module.export within the same module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a difference between the two in terms of performance(They currently perform the exact same functionality)?

```
 //EX1:
//Variables
const multiplier = 5;
const maxAttempts = 5;
const delay = 15;

module.exports = {
  delay: delay, //In minutes,
  maxAttempts: maxAttempts,
  multiplier: multiplier,
  passphrase: {
    minLength: 10,
  },
  muliply: (attempts) => {
    return Math.round(attempts / multiplier, 1);
  },
  duration: () => {
    return multiplier > 0 ? delay * multiplier : delay;
  },
  determine: (attempts) => {
    return attempts < maxAttempts;
  },
};
```

Or:

```
//EX2:
module.exports = {
  delay: 15, //In minutes,
  maxAttempts: 5,
  multiplier: 5,
  passphrase: {
    minLength: 10,
  },
  muliply: (attempts) => {
    return Math.round(attempts / module.exports.multiplier, 1);
  },
  duration: () => {
    return module.exports.multiplier > 0 ? module.exports.delay * module.exports.multiplier : module.exports.delay;
  },
  determine: (attempts) => {
    return attempts <module.exports.maxAttempts;
  },
};
```

1. If not, is there a downfall to using `module.exports['variableOrMethod']`?
2. Also, lets assume the code is the same with one difference. One is configured as an object(EX2)and another setup as a class. In most cases, you can set them up to do the same functionality.Is it better to create a class with the data or does `module.exports` ensure only data contained within `module.exports = ...` is included in the `require`?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no difference between the first and second code snippets,
   performance wise that is. If you try to access
   `module.exports['variableOrMethod']` it won't make a difference in
   either of the codes.
2. If your class contains a constructor which initializes the data, it will work just fine, there is no better or worse way. If you need to export a mapping of constant string to values, then better to just export the object with the values directly. You would prefer to export classes if you are using them for reusability purposes

EDIT: Pretty sure you know this, but javascript just uses classes as a syntactical sugar for js and converts them into objects anyway.

Comment: Awesome! Thats what i thought! But wasnt 100% confident